# Node.js mysql xdevapi пустой массив

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqlconnector

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('login', async ({ user, password }) => {
        dbconfig.user = user;
        dbconfig.password = password;
        try {
            dbconnect = await mysqlx.getSession(dbconfig);
            let databases = await dbconnect.getSchemas();

            console.log(`Databases`, databases);
            console.log(`Index 0`, databases[0].name);
            console.log(`Stringify Data`, JSON.stringify(databases));


            socket.emit("DATABASES", JSON.stringify(databases));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
            socket.emit("ERROR", err);
        }
    });
});
```

Вроде нормально возвращает базы данных, но при попытки сделать стингифай, почему то вот такое результат.
Так же я не могу обратиться к какому то элементу допустим к 0 и взять у его свойство name.
Использую mysql/xdevapi'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно официальной документации, чтобы получить имена баз данных:

```
// Connecting to MySQL and working with a Session
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

// Connect to a dedicated MySQL server using a connection URI
mysqlx
   .getSession('user:password@localhost')
   .then(function (mySession) {
   // Get a list of all available schemas
       return mySession.getSchemas();
   })
   .then(function (schemaList) {
      console.log('Available schemas in this session:\n');

      // Loop over all available schemas and print their name
      schemaList.forEach(function (schema) {
        console.log(schema.getName() + '\n');
      });
    });
```

В вашем случае:

```
// Loop over all available schemas and print their name
   databases.forEach(function (schema) {
      console.log(schema.getName() + '\n');
   });
```

Похоже, что с полученными вами Schema Objects нельзя работать как с javascript объектом, поэтому JSON.stringify здесь не уместно.

Здесь описано, как работать с такими объектами и какие функции доступны:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/crud-ebnf-schema-objects-and-functions.html

Comment: блин вот почему вечно, вроде бы это должно рассматриваться чуть ли не в гет стартед, а по итогу, почти в конце документации. Сидел залипал 2 дня, не мог понять в чем проблема.